# How do I prompt for user input in bash? Please fix my python/bash Spanglish

Tags: python, bash

Sorry. I am very new to this and can't find a straight forward answer. In python I can say:

```
from sys import argv
script, user_name = argv
prompt'> '
print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script" % (user_name, script)
print "I'd like to ask you a few questions"
print "What channel is that on?"
channel = raw_input(prompt)
blah blah -c %r  % (channel)
```

I need to be able to either accomplish the same thing with raw_input() in a regular bash (.sh) shell script     **OR**  I need to be able to manipulate other programs from within a python script   **OR**   I need to be able to launch a second shell (bash)from within a python script.

Please be gentle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module if you want to launch other programs from python. As for manipulating other programs -- you'd have to be more specific about the manipulation but I have found that I can do everything in python that I used to do in bash plus a whole lot more. If you are new to python, you should be sleeping with the Library Reference under your pillow. I've been doing python for years and I still refer to it a lot when I am programming.

Comment: Thanks much. This is exactly what I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are looking for [read](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#EX36) internal command

```
echo -n "What channel is that on? ";
read channel;
```

Or more concisely

```
read -p "What channel is that on? " channel
```

Comment: `echo -n` isn't portable; use `read -p "What channel is that on? " channel` instead.  Also, you don't need semicolons at the end of lines.

Comment: **echo -n** also is not portable, instead use POSIX shell built-in - **printf** which work more like plain C printf))